# Speculative execution for reducers in Hadoop not triggered

Tags: hadoop, reducers, speculative-execution

I have set the following flags so that speculative execution gets triggered for my MR jobs. There is some bad hardware causing jobs to run very long (8-9 hours instead of regular 1.5 - 3 hours) and ideally the hardware issue should not impact Hadoop MR job run times when we have speculation on. The mappers work fine and trigger speculation but no speculation is ever triggered on the reducers (even those that run for 8 hours). Any help in this situation would be extremely valuable.

Source for the param values: http://docs.qubole.com/en/latest/user-guide/hadoop/hadoop1/speculation.html

```
 mapred.speculative.reduce.lag=120000
 mapreduce.reduce.speculative=true
 mapreduce.job.speculative.stddevmeanratio.max=0.8
 mapred.speculative.reduce.duration=300 
 mapred.reduce.tasks.speculation.unfinished.threshold=0.001
```

Comment: did you try to increase number of reducers to have more splits of smaller size?

Comment: @AdamSkywalker: yes I tried bumping by 1000 reducers but did not help with triggering speculation for reducers